# Python: Rounding to Nearest 1/8%

Tags: python, math, decimal, rounding, average

I'm trying to calculate the average weighted interest rates of loans in Python 2.7.

I started out with floats, and that was problematic. Given these inputs (Loan #1 $20,000 6.80%; Loan #2 $10,000 7.90%; Loan #3 $10,000 5.41%) the correct result is 6.7275. Using Decimal, my code outputs that.

However, I am supposed to take that number and round <del>up</del> to the nearest 1/8% and display the result as 6.75 instead. When I use format to round to two places, I get 6.73. While that is what I would expect, is does not meet the scope of what this function should do.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def weightedAvgFixedArgs(r1,r2,r3,b1,b2,b3):
    rates = [Decimal(r1),Decimal(r2),Decimal(r3)]
    balances = [Decimal(b1),Decimal(b2),Decimal(b3)]

    a = Decimal(b1) * Decimal(r1)
    b = Decimal(b2) * Decimal(r2)
    c = Decimal(b3) * Decimal(r3)

    perLoanWghtFctr = a + b + c

    totalLoanAmt = sum(balances)

    intRate = (perLoanWghtFctr / totalLoanAmt) * 100

    return format(intRate, '.2f')
```

Edit: Joachim Isaksson's suggestion provides the output I requested with the inputs I provided. I haven't tested this extensively in my particular use-case, but it correctly answers the question I asked.

```
# return format(intRate, '.2f')
z = intRate * 8
y = format(z, '.0f')
x = Decimal(y) / Decimal(8)
return x
```

Comment: Multiply by 8, round up to nearest integer, divide by 8?

Comment: I'm sure you mean to the nearest `1/4`, right?

Comment: @pp_ I was specifically told "next nearest 1/8%", but the person asking me for this could have made a mistake.

Comment: Your code returns `672.75` for the input provided?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Unit test of (0.0680,0.0790,0.0541,20000,10000,10000) returns 6.73. But yes, should I include more places it would go to 6.7275.

Comment: Ah ok, 7.90  vs 0.0790, I think   you want the ceiling not to round

Answer (score 3):

To round up to the nearest 1/8%:

```
import math

>>> math.ceil(.73 * 8) / 8
0.75

>>> math.ceil(.76 * 8) / 8
0.875
```

Comment: ...and 0.76 is rounded up to...?

Comment: It rounds down to 0.75.  The cut-off is 0.8125 before it next rounds up to 0.875

Comment: "...take that number and round _up_ to the nearest..."

Comment: Good point, I noticed "When I use format to round to two places"

Answer (score 0):

Multiply 8, round or truncate as you want, then divide by 8, here is the sample code:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    v = i/10.0
    v = round(v*8) / 8.0
    print i/10.0, v
```

Run it you will get:

```
0.0 0.0
0.1 0.125
0.2 0.25
0.3 0.25
0.4 0.375
0.5 0.5
0.6 0.625
0.7 0.75
0.8 0.75
0.9 0.875
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically told to round **up**, you should use [ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

```
import math

x = 6.7275
x = math.ceil(x * 8)/8  # x == 6.75
```

Answer (score 0):

When calculating the *Weighted Average Interest rate*, you will have to ROUND UP.
Some source(s) about calculation related to interest rates:

- [Tutorial: Calculating the Weighted Average Interest Rate](https://www.edvisors.com/repay-student-loans/federal/consolidation/calculate-weighted-average-interest-rates/)
- [Weighted Average Interest Rate Calculator](https://www.studentdebtrelief.us/weighted-average-interest-rate-calculator/)
- [Interest Rates on Federal Consolidation Loans](https://www.savingforcollege.com/article/interest-rates-on-federal-consolidation-loans)
- [Federal Student Financial Aid Handbook](https://books.google.nl/books?id=7egUf0bWTh4C&pg=RA7-PA14&lpg=RA7-PA14&dq=why%20round%20up%20weighted%20average%20interest%20rate?&source=bl&ots=AZv734X3qI&sig=ACfU3U0YhI-5J7Fl1a_iNp1Ml3X1Bid66g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ4tiJx43oAhUyMewKHVZqAgUQ6AEwDHoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=why%20round%20up%20weighted%20average%20interest%20rate%3F&f=false)

I think this is the best way to do what you are asking for:

```
import math
x = 6.73
math.ceil(x / (1/8)) * (1/8)
```

I personally do not have a clear (mathematical) explanation of why doing first the multiplication and then later the division also works. Or doing it with value 8 instead of 1/8. The example below also seems to work:

```
math.ceil(x * (8)) / 8
```

Both works. In the first example, you are able to use it as the given value, which is (1/8), and at the second example you are able to use ut as a whole number, in this case, it's 8.
If you want to round to just the nearest 1/8% (and not *round up* to the nearest 1/8%, as it's supposed to be), that is a different case.